# BOOST_ROOT not respected at link stage after cmake config

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Apologies for a lengthy title.

I am struggling linking boost with `cmake` due to existence of boost libraries in `/usr/lib64` directory. My boost is compiled in a different place and I am pointing `cmake` with `BOOST_ROOT`. Aware of potential problems I am setting a minimal version and `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATH`. Configure stage works fine, but when linking I get an error:

```
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0xa8): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
 >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
```

This is clearly a problem of picking up the wrong library and I can see with `make VERBOSE=2` that the `g++` line doesn't respect my previously found boost setting in `BOOST_ROOT`

```
g++ CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -o test -rdynamic -lboost_program_options-mt
```

But I would expect something along these lines:

```
g++ ... -L/path/to/my/own/boost/lib -lboost_program_options-mt
```

As a "debug" step I print out a message in `cmake` with `Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS` and I can see `/path/to/my/own/boost/lib`. When I "manually" add the `-L` flag the linking works, which is how I know that the system libs are still interfering. Also, my `*LIBRARY_PATH` are pointing only at `/path/to/my/own/boost/lib`.

Perhaps, it's not unlikely that this is a bug of `FindBoost` module, but I am finding it hard to believe. It seems to me that there's still something major in cmake I do not understand? Why is the `-L` flag not generated in this instance or a link to a specific file? Please advise.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.67.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(test test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})
```

And my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po=boost::program_options;

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
    po::options_description options_description;
    po::positional_options_description positional_options_description;
    po::variables_map variables_map;


    options_description.add_options()
    ("help,h", "print usage message");
    po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(
        options_description).positional(positional_options_description).run(),
        variables_map);

    return 0; 
}
```

#### Other relevant output

I am using `message` to pull out varables from `cmake` config step after `find_package`:

```
${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} /path/to/my/own/boost/include
${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} /path/to/my/own/boost/lib
${Boost_LIBRARIES} /path/to/my/own/boost/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so
${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY} /path/to/my/own/boost/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so
```

Comment: `-L` is always added if required. You haven't specified int he question what the value should be or if `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` has the full path. BTW, should be `${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY}` (IIRC). The other option is to set the library as a source, otherwise it will always use `-l`.

Comment: Thanks @MatthieuBrucher  I added my expectations. My actual directory name is pretty long due to the complicated directory structure on the server, but I hope a simple /path/to form is OK. I've also tried the program options, but it's the same effect.

Comment: What do you have in `${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY}`? If I ask the content of a specific variable, there is a reason...

Comment: @RobertSawko: The debugging first step when face with unexpected link libraries/include directories/whatever is to **check variables** which you use in the code. Your code uses variables `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY`, so check that they have reasonable values. Only after this step is performed, you may go deeper - check semantic of used commands (`find_package`), and so on.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, I wasn't clear about this, but I have checked it. I have now added a section in my question. To me all looks good. My main surprise is that these variables appear to be correct and yet no -L in `make`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I have now added a section with various outputs from `message` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling in on `cmake-developer` mailing list and finally leaving a post on  [cmake gitlab issues](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18873) I realised that the problem was not so much my cmake version, but rather my `cmake_minimum_required` which I inherited from an older project.

I was setting:

```
cmake_minium_required(VERSION 2.8)
```

After updating it to 3.12 that I got the correct behaviour:

```
/path/to/g++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o -o test -lboost_program_options-mt
```

Reading [cmake_minimum_required](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) docs I understood that "command implicitly invokes" `cmake_policy`. I believe the latter wasn't playing well with `FindBoost` from my 3.12 `cmake.

I am not sure if this post is useful to SO, but I have certainly learnt my cmake lesson here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which CMake version you are using but did you try using Boost imported target instead of the old-fashioned CMake variable:

i.e.
replace:
`target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})`
by
`target_link_libraries(test LINK_PUBLIC Boost::program_options)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have cmake 3.12 so I will start using the newer syntax from now on.